# Header and many components missing in Open Social

Tags: installation

Just installed Open Social:
https://www.drupal.org/project/social

The problem is that there is no content on the front page. No header or other blocks. I have reviewed videos of installation on YouTube, and notice that there is a header, and many other blocks available by default immediately after installation. Why does my new instance of Open Social have nothing on the home page?

I followed the install instructions on the module page:
https://www.drupal.org/project/social

Answer (score 0):

Generating demo content is optional but recommended. 
Follow these [instructions on generating demo content](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/distributions/open-social/create-demo-content) (Drush support only for now).
Still stuck? Explore the thorough guide to [installing and updating](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/distributions/open-social/installing-and-updating) which includes help for working with Docker.

OR

drush command to add demo content

```
drush demo-content-add file user group topic event event_enrollment comment post like
```